# Trouble making a JSON string

Tags: json

I'm trying to upgrade an existing JSON structure to a more complex one.

The original idea is a bunch of X **animals**, each one having a bunch of caracteristics:

- animals

  - animal 1

    - claws:4
    - eyes:2
  - animal 2

    - claws:0
    - eyes:6
  - etc.

The JSON is like this:

```
{
    "animals":[
        {"claws":"4", "eyes":"2"},
        {"claws":"0", "eyes":"6"},
        etc.
    ]
}
```

So as you can see, I don't name each animal object, the caracteristics of an animal are an element of the array. I can use them in a loop like *animals[x].claws*

---

Now I want to add a nest for each animal, like:

- animals

  - animal 1

    - head

      - eyes:2
      - ears:2
    - body

      - claws:4
      - tails:1
      - legs:4
  - animal 2

    - head

      - eyes:6
      - ears:0
    - body

      - claws:0
      - tails:0
      - legs:8

But I didn't manage to do it without naming each animal object (with the same name "animal") and using arrays for what's in an animal:

```
{
    "animals":[
        {"animal":[
            {"head":
                {"eyes":"2", "ears":"2"}
            },
            {"body":
                {"claws":"4", "tails":"1", "legs":"4"}
            }
        ]},
        {"animal":[
            {"head":
                {"eyes":"6", "ears":"0"}
            },
            {"body":
                {"claws":"0", "tails":"0", "legs":"8"}
            }  
        ]}
    ]
}
```

I find it sucky because:

1) I don't need a name for each animal structure (especially since they are all named "animal") since I wanna iterate on them as an array like before;

2) I don't need an array for *head* and *body* since I know the number and names of elements.

I wish I could use something like that but it doesn't work:

```
{
    "animals":[
        {
            {"head":
                {"eyes":"2", "ears":"2"}
            },
            {"body":
                {"claws":"4", "tails":"1", "legs":"4"}
            }
        },
        {
            {"head":
                {"eyes":"6", "ears":"0"}
            },
            {"body":
                {"claws":"0", "tails":"0", "legs":"8"}
            }  
        }
    ]
}
```

So is there a way of nesting without using arrays and names?

Comment: `{"animals": [{"head": {"eyes": "2","ears": "2"},"body": {"claws": "4","tails": "1","legs": "4"}}, {"head": {"eyes": "6","ears": "0"},"body": {"claws": "0","tails": "0","legs": "8"}}]}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is! Hash is a **key-value** pair, and that's why you need a key, when you use `{}`. Array is a simple **collection**. So `{}` can't be a *simple collection* (that's why you had to use *keys*, and the latter one didn't work, because `{}` in your example was a simple collection, look: `{ {}, {}, {} ... }`, so in this case it had to be `[ {}, {}, {} ... ]`), but you can make it simpler, just don't nest it so many times:

```
{
    "animals":[
        {
            "head": {
                "eyes":"2", 
                "ears":"2"
            },
            "body": {
                "claws":"4", 
                "tails":"1", 
                "legs":"4"
            }
        },
        # ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you and Larme. I didn't even realize *head* and *body* were keys and the following curvy braces elements were values... JSON is my worst enemy. Thanks mate.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps no problem!